# Why did Patrick Jane have to steal the suspect list from LaRoche by hiring Donny Cullpepper?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mentalist

Ok so here's what I don't understand, on season 3 episode 10, Patrick approaches Virgil and convinces him to help him give the suspect list that J.J. LaRoche possessed. At the end of the episode we can see Virgil handing to Patrick the said list.

Fast forward many episodes later, in season 3 episode 20.

The episode starts with Donny Cullpepper breaking in J.J. LaRoches house, which ends up with him being caught by the police and it was ultimately revealed that Patrick hired him to steal the suspect list from LaRoche.

The same suspect list which supposedly was handed over to him by Virgil many episodes prior.

So my question is, why the need to steal the suspect list again? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In episode S3E10 Jane got the whole list of suspect. But in S3E20 he got top 4 suspect that is nearby the murder place and no one can prove that he/she is with them.

Comment: What your trying to say is that the second time, the list only contained the few suspects they could not cross off, and thus, was a lot more useful. Perhaps you could elaborate, in your answer.